# Use Union or Join to use multiple query results in a where statement

Tags: php, mysql

I need to combine results of 3 sum queries and echo the results in a loop. I am stuck on how this is done the right way. I would like to use a while loop to echo a row for each client that shows the results of the 3 sum queries grouped by the client name:

client name | Total Due | Total Due From Cash Sales | Total Due From Credit Sales

result shows all due to a client.
noncashresult shows all due to a client from Credit sales.
cashresult shows all due to a client from Cash sales.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `client_name` As `Client`, SUM(`due_to_client`) As `Total Due` 
FROM `Consignment` 
WHERE `payout_approved` = 'Yes' 
GROUP BY `client_name`"); 

$noncashresult = mysql_query("SELECT `client_name` As `Client`, SUM(`due_to_client`) As `Credit Total Due`
FROM `Consignment` 
WHERE `payout_approved` = 'Yes' AND `paymenttype` IN ('Credit') 
GROUP BY `client_name`");

$cashresult = mysql_query("SELECT `client_name` As `Client`, SUM(`due_to_client`) As `Cash Total Due`
FROM `Consignment` 
WHERE `payout_approved` = 'Yes' AND `paymenttype` IN ('Cash') 
GROUP BY `client_name`");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                echo $row['Client'];
                echo $row['Total Due'];
                echo $row['Credit Total Due'];
                echo $row['Cash Total Due'];
                    }
```

Comment: Hi Craig, if it were me, I would collect the results of each query into an array organized by client. Then you could simply print out each clients information while looping through the array.
Am I missing something?
Alternately, it looks like you might be able to use a UNION between each query & get what you're looking for (except a UNION will require that the aliases for each column be the same which might make your results difficult to understand/keep the meaning for each result).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
SELECT `client_name` As `Client`,
SUM(`due_to_client`) As `Total Due`,
SUM(CASE WHEN `paymenttype`='Credit' THEN `due_to_client` ELSE 0 END) As `Credit Total Due`,
SUM(CASE WHEN `paymenttype`='Cash' THEN `due_to_client` ELSE 0 END) As `Cash Total Due`
FROM `Consignment` 
WHERE `payout_approved` = 'Yes' 
GROUP BY `client_name`
```

This should produce result:

```
Client | Total Due | Credit Total Due | Cash Total Due
```

Of course, try to avoid using mysql_* extension, while this was deprecated in mysql 5.5.x. Instead use mysqli or pdo extension

Comment: Thank you, there was typo, i just edited it - try it now

Comment: That did it. Thank you. Now I will need to study to understand the query.

Comment: It is quite simple, `SUM(CASE WHEN \`paymenttype\`='Credit' THEN \`due_to_client\` ELSE 0 END)` means that check every row and if `\`paymenttype\`='Credit'` then add `due_to_client` value else add `0` to each client where payout_approved='Yes'